# Python FileInput WEIRD BEHAVIOUR

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following problem: I'm willing to replace some substring in a yaml file using python. I've managed to make it work using `fileInput` but harcoding what I want to search / find. If I use variables instead (and that's what I want at the end), IT DOESN'T WORK!!

Not sure what can be happening here... Here's my code:

```
def replace_version_in_config_file(local_filename, current_version, version):
    logging.info("replacing version " + str(current_version) + " for version " + str(version) + " in file " + str(local_filename))
    with fileinput.FileInput(local_filename, inplace=False, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace(str(current_version), str(version)), end='')
```

Now if I call this function this way, the code works with no problem:

```
replace_version_in_config_file("/tmp/multiconnect-coreapp.yml", "2.0", "3.0")
```

But if I use variables instead, it doesn't:

```
replace_version_in_config_file(str(file_to_change), str(old_version), str(new_version))
```

I've already checked the variables, and they have what they suppose to have inside them:

```
2020-10-02 13:57:16,504 :: WARNING :: configfile: /tmp/multiconnect-coreapp.yml
2020-10-02 13:57:16,504 :: WARNING :: current version: 2.27.8,
2020-10-02 13:57:16,504 :: WARNING :: version: 2.29.3,
```

I'm `str'ing` them when passed to the function just in case.
What I'm searching ("2.27.8" in this case, exists in the file I'm working on.

I just can't find what's going on here.

Comment: A variable holding a string and the same string as a literal will have the same behavior. Make sure there aren't any unprintable/difficult to see characters in the strings held in the variables. And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: "It doesn't work" means that it won't replace the substring in the file, even though is in there. If I run the same function but using literal text instead of variables, the function works as a charm! Now, if I run it using variables (with the proper values inside them, of course) it won't make any replacement. Not sure if it's not make the replacement, or not finding what's it's supposed to.